# Find a Global Sink in a graph

Tags: graphs, depth-first-search

There is a class exercise question asking about global sink in a directed graph.
Finding normal sink is not difficult but the conditions of the question have made me stuck on this question.

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph for which you have an adjacency
> list. A vertex $v$ is called a *global sink* if and only if it meets
> the following two conditions:
>
> 1. $v$ has no outgoing edges
> 2. for every vertex $u$, there is a path from $u$ to $v$

The question wants an algorithm that runs linearly.
Can you please provide a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a path from every vertex $u$ to some vertex $v$ in graph $G$ if and only if there is a path from $v$ to all vertices $u$ in the reversed graph $G^{R}$.

Comment: So, Should I run The SCC algorithm, find the components, look at the singletons, and see if all vertices are met in the reversed graph using one of those?

Comment: Not necessarily, all you need to know is if there is a path from $v$ to all the other vertices.

Comment: thank you for your help.